# file_put_content adds empty lines in file

Tags: codemirror, file-put-contents

I am using CodeMirror to edit files in my application. To save the file I put the textarea-content in a form. Then I use

```
file_put_contents($filepath, $POST['textarea_name']):
```

This works fine and the file looks great in CodeMirror too. But when I take a look at the real files there are many empty lines added.

Example (dummy code):

```
<?php

if ( a > f) {
    echo 'test';
}

function test() {

}

?>
```

becomes:

```
<?php



if ( a > f) {

    echo 'test';

}



function test() {



}



?>
```

Does anyone has any idea where these lines are coming from?

Comment: Could you check your line endings, e.g. with a hex editor? Maybe there were some Windows line endings in there (CRLF), which were transformed into multiple LFs, or your editor is not capable of rendering those.

Comment: It looks like there really is a problem with Windows because when I open the file in the browser the lines are still looking good. Unfortunately I have no idea how to tackle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I found a solution:

The files where saved with Windows EOL (CRLF) instead of Unix (LF).

```
str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $filecontent );
```

This should fix the issue. It did work for me.

Credit: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/9616